# Connecting controllers with interface builder?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I've been reading the documentation but I can't find a way to do this. It's probably something really simple.

Say I have a class called Table which is a subclass of UITableViewController. Table has a head and implementation file, Table.h and Table.m

Now, in my root view controller, I want to drop a UITableViewController into the nib, make that UITableViewController a Table, and set its delegate and datasource so that I can implement its protocol methods in Table.m

So I included Table.h in my RootViewController.h and .m, I set up a Table *table instance variable and a @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet Table *table, and I drop a UITableViewController onto RootViewController.xib. I then go to the identity inspector and try to change the class to Table, but this doesn't seem to work.

So in summary, I want to subclass UITableViewController and put an instance of that in my RootViewController.xib. My RootViewController is a SplitViewController, and my goal is to have a Table View in the left window and a Navigation View in the right.

Comment: Are you trying to change the rootviewcontroller to a tableviewcontroller?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm trying to drag and drop a UITableViewController into the left panel of the Split View, and I want that UITableViewController to be an instance of my custom subclass which sends delegate messages to itself.

Comment: Got it. I needed to put an "Object" (search for "object" in the object library in the interface builder) on the left side of the interface builder window (on the bar where File's Owner and First Responder are), change that object's class to Table, then drag a UITableView into interface builder and wire it (delegate and data source) to my Table object on the side bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to put an "Object" (search for "object" in the object library in the interface builder) on the left side of the interface builder window (on the bar where File's Owner and First Responder are), change that object's class to Table, then drag a UITableView into interface builder and wire it (delegate and data source) to my Table object on the side bar.